# Просмотр ассемблерного кода в GDB

Tags: gdb, ассемблер

Как в GDB просмотреть ассемблерный код функции? Например, для кода:

```
void main() {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать командой disassemble (disas):

```
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x08048394 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x08048395 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048397 <+3>: pop    %ebp
   0x08048398 <+4>: ret    
End of assembler dump.
```